# Javmail getting Multipart message Content

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail, multipart

I'm working on an email client for my Android Phone, and I want to get the Content of a message wich is in Multipart format.

The text/plain content I get on the following way:

```
public String getContent(Part p) {

    Object contentObject = null;

    try {

        if (p.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
            if (!showStructure && !saveAttachments)
                contentObject = p.getContent();
        }

        InputStream is = (InputStream) contentObject;
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }

        String everything = sb.toString();

        System.out.println(everything);
        return everything;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "Fehler: " + e;
    }
}
```

How can I get the Content text of a Multipart Message? I already tried this:

```
[...]
} else if (p.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
            Multipart mp = (Multipart) p.getContent();
            level++;
            int count = mp.getCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                contentObject = getContent(mp.getBodyPart(i));
            level--;
}
```

(...) Then the InputStream Reader, but then I get the Exception IMAPInputStream cannot be cast to javax.mail.Multipart.

Comment: See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#castmultipart

Comment: I put "Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());", but it don't work :( Other Ideas?

Comment: Does anybody have an idea how I can get the text from a Multipart Message?

Answer (score -1):

You should start with a request, like

```
ServletRequest request
```

After this you take the request and ask if it is a Multipart request. I hope this helps

```
 HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = null;      
    if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
        httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    }   

    CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    if (commonsMultipartResolver.isMultipart(httpServletRequest)) {
        if (commonsMultipartResolver.isMultipart(null)) {
            try {
                MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartHttpServletRequest =  commonsMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(httpServletRequest);
                Enumeration<String> enumKey = multipartHttpServletRequest.getParameterNames();
                while(enumKey.hasMoreElements()) {
                    String key = enumKey.nextElement();
                    System.out.println("multipart " + key + ": " +  multipartHttpServletRequest.getParameter(key));                
                }               
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Exception TEST: " + ex);
            }
        }
    }
```